# laravel eloquent: return model without dates/specific variable

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

Is there buildIn option to get model without date of another column?
something like this:

```
Mymodel::all() -> without('createdAt', 'id')
```

I can work on the result after I get it and cut what i dont need. But I think it might be possible to get result I need, since I can do it sql.
Thanks

Comment: What is your usecase here? You can define the columns you need in `->all(['x','y'])`, or use something like `pluck()`, though there is no `without` or `except` method. If you just want to filter vars for output and your output is json, @Vitalmax's answer will be just fine. If not, your question is not clear about what you actually need it for.

Comment: Hey, vitalmax's answer is good. working well for me. 
I didnt knew that i can use ->all(['a', 'b']). good to know.
thanks

Comment: pluck works, but if i want to choose what NOT to show, "hidden" method is better

Comment: Cool :) Just keep in mind that hidden will only work on output where `toArray()` is called. I guess in your case it works, but when you output the model in a view somewhere, those fields will show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hidden` property can be used if you work with `toArray()`:

> Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes, such as passwords,
>   that are included in your model's array or JSON representation. To do
>   so, add a $hidden property to your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: this will only work when the toArray() method is used

Comment: @Robert Thanks, pal. I've updated my answer to make it more clear.